# Oracle SQL: How to add day intervals to dates?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, intervals

I want to add day intervals to a list of dates in Oracle SQL, to the next week's Monday. However, I am getting a very weird error when I use the suggested `date + 1` kind of interval, wherein only one day is getting add up as expected, i.e., `Wednesday`. What am I doing wrong here? Is this a bug in Oracle SQL Developer?

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT '29-JAN-23' dt FROM dual UNION
    SELECT '30-JAN-23' dt FROM dual UNION
    SELECT '31-JAN-23' dt FROM dual UNION
    SELECT '01-FEB-23' dt FROM dual UNION
    SELECT '02-FEB-23' dt FROM dual UNION
    SELECT '03-FEB-23' dt FROM dual UNION
    SELECT '04-FEB-23' dt FROM dual UNION
    SELECT '05-FEB-23' dt FROM dual UNION
    SELECT '06-FEB-23' dt FROM dual UNION
    SELECT '07-FEB-23' dt FROM dual UNION
    SELECT '08-FEB-23' dt FROM dual UNION
    SELECT '09-FEB-23' dt FROM dual
)

SELECT
    TO_DATE(dt) dt,
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(dt),'DAY') dt_day,
    CASE
        WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(dt),'DAY') = 'MONDAY'      THEN TO_DATE(dt)
        WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(dt),'DAY') = 'TUSEDAY'     THEN TO_DATE(dt) + 6
        WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(dt),'DAY') = 'WEDNESDAY'   THEN TO_DATE(dt) + 5
        WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(dt),'DAY') = 'THURSDAY'    THEN TO_DATE(dt) + 4
        WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(dt),'DAY') = 'FRIDAY'      THEN TO_DATE(dt) + 3
        WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(dt),'DAY') = 'SATURDAY'    THEN TO_DATE(dt) + 2
        WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(dt),'DAY') = 'SUNDAY'      THEN TO_DATE(dt) + 1
    END new_dt
FROM data
ORDER BY TO_DATE(dt)
;
```

Output

```
| DT        | DT_DAY    | NEW_DT    |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 29-JAN-23 | SUNDAY    |           |
| 30-JAN-23 | MONDAY    |           |
| 31-JAN-23 | TUESDAY   |           |
| 01-FEB-23 | WEDNESDAY | 06-FEB-23 |
| 02-FEB-23 | THURSDAY  |           |
| 03-FEB-23 | FRIDAY    |           |
| 04-FEB-23 | SATURDAY  |           |
| 05-FEB-23 | SUNDAY    |           |
| 06-FEB-23 | MONDAY    |           |
| 07-FEB-23 | TUESDAY   |           |
| 08-FEB-23 | WEDNESDAY | 13-FEB-23 |
| 09-FEB-23 | THURSDAY  |           |
```

Comment: `TO_DATE(dt)` is a deeply unreliable way of handling dates. Try defining dates [as literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Literals.html) e.g. `date '2023-01-29'`. Also, the `'DAY'` date format mask right-pads up to the length of Wednesday, so you either need to handle that or else use `'DY'` which gives a 3-letter abbreviated day name, although you should bear in mind nls_date_language. Also, you could do the conversion just once and only use a `case` expression to generate the offset to add. Or indeed look into the `'IW'` format mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things: use format mask for to_date, then keep in mind that 'DAY' returns a string that is filled with blanks up to a certain length.
Therefore:

```
WITH data AS (
SELECT '29-JAN-23' dt FROM dual UNION
SELECT '30-JAN-23' dt FROM dual UNION
SELECT '31-JAN-23' dt FROM dual UNION
SELECT '01-FEB-23' dt FROM dual UNION
SELECT '02-FEB-23' dt FROM dual UNION
SELECT '03-FEB-23' dt FROM dual UNION
SELECT '04-FEB-23' dt FROM dual UNION
SELECT '05-FEB-23' dt FROM dual UNION
SELECT '06-FEB-23' dt FROM dual UNION
SELECT '07-FEB-23' dt FROM dual UNION
SELECT '08-FEB-23' dt FROM dual UNION
SELECT '09-FEB-23' dt FROM dual
```

)

```
SELECT
    TO_DATE(dt) dt,
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(dt,'dd-mon-rr'),'DAY') dt_day,
    CASE
        WHEN trim(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(dt,'dd-mon-rr'),'DAY')) = 'MONDAY'      THEN TO_DATE(dt,'dd-mon-rr')
        WHEN trim(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(dt,'dd-mon-rr'),'DAY')) = 'TUSEDAY'     THEN TO_DATE(dt,'dd-mon-rr') + 6
        WHEN trim(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(dt,'dd-mon-rr'),'DAY')) = 'WEDNESDAY'   THEN TO_DATE(dt,'dd-mon-rr') + 5
        WHEN trim(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(dt,'dd-mon-rr'),'DAY')) = 'THURSDAY'    THEN TO_DATE(dt,'dd-mon-rr') + 4
        WHEN trim(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(dt,'dd-mon-rr'),'DAY')) = 'FRIDAY'      THEN TO_DATE(dt,'dd-mon-rr') + 3
        WHEN trim(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(dt,'dd-mon-rr'),'DAY')) = 'SATURDAY'    THEN TO_DATE(dt,'dd-mon-rr') + 2
        WHEN trim(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(dt,'dd-mon-rr'),'DAY')) = 'SUNDAY'      THEN TO_DATE(dt,'dd-mon-rr') + 1
    END new_dt
FROM data
ORDER BY TO_DATE(dt,'dd-mon-rr')
;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's adding the `TRIM` that fixed the issue for me.

Comment: You can also do `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(dt,'dd-mon-rr'),'FMDAY')` - the `FM` modifier stops it padding the string, so you don't then need to trim it. (I'd also prefer to specify `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` via the optional third argument to `to_char()` and `to_date`, just in case.)

Answer (score 5):

Your conversion can be simplified to:

```
TRUNC(<original_date> + 6,'IW')
```

The `IW` [format element](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-49B32A81-0904-433E-B7FE-51606672183A) is the ISO calendar week, which always starts on a Monday, and truncating to that gives you the same week-start date for each day of that week; adding six adjusts for you essentially starting on Tuesday instead.

So converting your strings to dates first that becomes:

```
TRUNC(TO_DATE(dt,'dd-mon-rr','nls_date_language=english') + 6,'IW')
```

(Not that you should be storing dates as strings, of course; they are in your sample-data CTE but maybe check the data type you're really working with, and you aren't just assuming you need to convert because you *see* actual dates in that format in your client...)

With your current CTE that gets the same result:

```
SELECT
    TO_DATE(dt) dt,
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(dt,'dd-mon-rr','nls_date_language=english'),'FMDAY','nls_date_language=english') dt_day,
    TRUNC(TO_DATE(dt,'dd-mon-rr','nls_date_language=english') + 6,'IW') new_dt
FROM data
ORDER BY TO_DATE(dt,'dd-mon-rr','nls_date_language=english')
;
```

| DT | DT_DAY | NEW_DT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 29-JAN-23 | SUNDAY | 30-JAN-23 |
| 30-JAN-23 | MONDAY | 30-JAN-23 |
| 31-JAN-23 | TUESDAY | 06-FEB-23 |
| 01-FEB-23 | WEDNESDAY | 06-FEB-23 |
| 02-FEB-23 | THURSDAY | 06-FEB-23 |
| 03-FEB-23 | FRIDAY | 06-FEB-23 |
| 04-FEB-23 | SATURDAY | 06-FEB-23 |
| 05-FEB-23 | SUNDAY | 06-FEB-23 |
| 06-FEB-23 | MONDAY | 06-FEB-23 |
| 07-FEB-23 | TUESDAY | 13-FEB-23 |
| 08-FEB-23 | WEDNESDAY | 13-FEB-23 |
| 09-FEB-23 | THURSDAY | 13-FEB-23 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aujepTmW)

I've included the optional third argument to `to_date()` so the month abbreviations will be recognised even if the session date language is something else. Another thing you don't need to worry about if you start with real dates instead of strings.

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify your generator to:

```sql
WITH data (dt) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2023-01-29' + LEVEL - 1
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY DATE '2023-01-29' + LEVEL - 1 <= DATE '2023-02-09'
)
SELECT dt,
       TO_CHAR(dt,'fmDAY') dt_day,
       CASE
       WHEN dt = TRUNC(dt, 'IW')
       THEN dt 
       ELSE TRUNC(dt, 'IW') + 7
       END new_dt
FROM   data
ORDER BY dt;
```

Which outputs:

| DT | DT_DAY | NEW_DT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-29 00:00:00 | SUNDAY | 2023-01-30 00:00:00 |
| 2023-01-30 00:00:00 | MONDAY | 2023-01-30 00:00:00 |
| 2023-01-31 00:00:00 | TUESDAY | 2023-02-06 00:00:00 |
| 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | WEDNESDAY | 2023-02-06 00:00:00 |
| 2023-02-02 00:00:00 | THURSDAY | 2023-02-06 00:00:00 |
| 2023-02-03 00:00:00 | FRIDAY | 2023-02-06 00:00:00 |
| 2023-02-04 00:00:00 | SATURDAY | 2023-02-06 00:00:00 |
| 2023-02-05 00:00:00 | SUNDAY | 2023-02-06 00:00:00 |
| 2023-02-06 00:00:00 | MONDAY | 2023-02-06 00:00:00 |
| 2023-02-07 00:00:00 | TUESDAY | 2023-02-13 00:00:00 |
| 2023-02-08 00:00:00 | WEDNESDAY | 2023-02-13 00:00:00 |
| 2023-02-09 00:00:00 | THURSDAY | 2023-02-13 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/G_Gow8Oe)

> What am I doing wrong here?

`TO_DATE(date_value, 'DAY')` outputs a fixed-length string that is the length of the longest day name in your language. For English that is `'WEDNESDAY'` and other strings would be padded with blanks such as `'MONDAY   '`.

If you want to not pad the string then use `TO_DATE(date_value, 'fmDAY')` and then your code will work (if you spell `TUESDAY` correctly and the implicit date conversion succeeds).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-Ksyya15)